# Requesting https using HttpURLConnection

Tags: android, https

I am using `HttpURLConnection` to request server.
Previously server was using `http only protocol`, while now its using https protocol.

My question is I am not using `HttpsURLConnection` still my code is working fine, how is it possible when I am not adding certificate still its working.

Below is my code

```
//url is https://.......

URL m_url = new URL(p_url);
        m_httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) m_url.openConnection();

        m_httpConnection.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
        m_httpConnection.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
        System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
        m_httpConnection.setUseCaches(false);
        m_httpConnection.setDoOutput(p_isDoOutput);
        if (p_contentType != null)
        {
            m_httpConnection.setRequestProperty("content-type", p_contentType);
        }
        m_httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate,sdch");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`HttpsURLConnection` extends `HttpURLConnection`, and your connection is an instance of both. When you call `openConnection()` the function actually returns an `HttpsURLConnection`. However, because the https object extends the http one, your connection is still an instance of an `HttpURLConnection`. This is why your cast works. You could also cast the connection to an `HttpsURLConnection` without issue.

Basically think of it like this. `openConnection()` returns a `URLConnection` object that DOES NOT support the HTTP protocol. However, as you seem to be aware in your code, that `URLConnection` is actually an `HttpURLConnection` that DOES support the HTTP protocol. In the same sense your `HttpURLConnection` is actually an `HttpsURLConnection` that DOES support SSL/TLS.

Comment: But as i have not add certificate still its working over http that i can't understand, i think it should necessary to add certificate if your working over https.

Comment: @AndroidWeblineindia I have never heard that an SSL client needs to provide a certificate. My understanding was that the server provides a certificate/key pair and the client authenticates it.